# Spring Integration - MessageTransformationException - MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of String

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Recently Updated my project to Spring boot to **2.2.X** from **2.1.X**

After updating the project getting below exception.

I am using spring provided JSON transformer to convert json string to object.

**myproject-context.xml**

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="updateProductDetailsQueueAdapter"
            channel="updateProductDetailsQueueChannel" queue-names="update-product-details-queue"
            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
            
<int:json-to-object-transformer
    input-channel="updateProductDetailsQueueChannel"
    output-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerInputChannel" type="org.somePackage.UpdateProductDetailsEvent" />

<int:transformer
    input-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerInputChannel"
    output-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerOutputChannel" expression="payload.getUpdateMessage()" />
```

**Model Class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UpdateProductDetailsEvent implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String productType;
  private String updateMessage;

  @JsonCreator
  public UpdateProductDetailsEvent(@JsonProperty("productType") String productType, @JsonProperty("updateMessage") String updateMessage) {
    this.productType = productType;
    this.updateMessage = updateMessage;
   }
}
```

```
  Caused by:
  org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to
  transform message; nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: 
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 
  `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
  at [Source: (String)"{"productType":"Electronics","updateMessage":"Description to update"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
  .........................
  .........................
  Caused by:
  java.io.UncheckedIOException: 
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 
  `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
  at [Source: (String)"{"productType":"Electronics","updateMessage":"Description to update"}"; line: 1, column: 1] at 
  org.springframework.integration.json.JsonToObjectTransformer.doTransform
  (JsonToObjectTransformer.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Any chances to share with us a simple Spring Boot project to reproduce and play with?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a solution, problem is due to `content-type` attribute not present in input message.
So object-to-json-transformer sets the `content-type` as `application/json` if header not present in the message.

I have suppressed the setting with empty string like `content-type=""`

[For more details - Read this spring blog](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-transformation.html)

```
<!-- My Out bound Queue configuration -->
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="productDetailsToUpdate"
    output-channel="outnoundChannel"  
    content-type="" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="outboundAdapterId" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
            channel="outboundDataExchange" exchange-name="update-product-details-exchange" /> 

<!-- My In bound Queue configuration -->
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="updateProductDetailsQueueAdapter"
            channel="updateProductDetailsQueueChannel" queue-names="update-product-details-queue"
            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
            
<int:json-to-object-transformer
    input-channel="updateProductDetailsQueueChannel"
    output-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerInputChannel" 
    type="org.somePackage.UpdateProductDetailsEvent" />

<int:transformer input-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerInputChannel"
    output-channel="updateProductDetailsTransformerOutputChannel" 
    expression="payload.getUpdateMessage()" />
```